# git commit using both verbose and message flags not working

Tags: git

I have a script that runs in a build pipeline which makes git commits.

I want the commit message to be fixed with no prompt and also the commit to be verbose.

When I use this format of command, the commit is not verbose:

`git commit -v -m 'commit message'`
`git commit --verbose -m 'commit message'`

What is the right correct way to structure this so I can supply the commit message to a verbose commit in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of a "verbose commit" in git.  The `-v` option makes the *process of committing* more verbose, in that it shows the diff in the editor where you're prompted to enter a commit message; but because you give the `-m` flag, that step is skipped.

I assume you're thinking that the diff is actually saved as part of the commit message, and that this is what makes the commit "verbose"?  Generally it's not.  If you fool git by removing all the comment lines that appear after where you're meant to type a message (but before the diff) then it will save the diff as the commit message.

I suppose you could do something like

```
git commit -m"$(git diff --staged)"
```

But the real question is: why do you want to do that?  If you want to see a log of commits with their patches, use `git log -p`.  Duplicating the diff in the commit message only serves to annoy people who want to see meaningful commit messages.

Answer (score 2):

`git commit -v` means "**open editor** to enter a commit message and show diff in the edited text".

`git commit -m message` means "**do not open an editor**, just use the supplied commit message".

These options are not compatible, there is no point in using them together.